# iOS MapKit Get Places information and Reviews

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I'm using mapkit and able to get Address for a particular location

```
let firstPlacemark = placemarks,
                let addressDictionary = firstPlacemark.addressDictionary else { return }
            //            let street = addressDictionary["Street"]
            //            let city = addressDictionary["City"]
            //            let state = addressDictionary["State"]
            //            let zip = addressDictionary["ZIP"]
            print(addressDictionary.description)
            if let array = addressDictionary["FormattedAddressLines"] as? [Any] {
                let address = array.map { "\($0)" }.joined(separator: ",\n")
                print("Address : \(address)")
            }
```

But Can we get more information like reviews contact no. images etc. Like Apple Maps shows (Observe Screeenshot)

[image]

Is there any API available in iOS for this or it will be provided via TripAdvisor???

**P.S: I don't want to Any Google API.**

Dear down voters if don't know the answers then kindly don't waste my points. It's easy to downvote, but you never know how much efforts has been added to earn those points. 
OR Kindly provide me solution or show me if question is duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tripadvisor API 
https://developer-tripadvisor.com/content-api/documentation/

ex.
http://api.tripadvisor.com/api/partner/2.0/location/155507?key=YOURKEY

Comment: As far as I know, they don’t provide API :-(